# Search using LIKE operator with multiple dynamic values accepting both full and partial text match

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there any way to do multiple term search in a column using like operator dynamically in SQL Server? Like below

```
SELECT ID 
FROM table 
WHERE 
   Company LIKE '%goog%' OR 
   Company LIKE '%micros%'  OR 
   Company LIKE '%amazon%'
```

For example: input values "goog; micro; amazon;" (input value should auto split by delimiter ';' and check the text exist in the table) means that Search term 'goog' or 'micros' or 'amazon' from company column, if exists return.

Table - sample data:

```
ID                 Company 
------------------------------------------
1                  Google; Microsoft; 
2                  oracle; microsoft; apple; walmart; tesla
3                  amazon; apple;
4                  google;
5                  tesla;        
6                  amazon;
```

Basically, The above query should return the results as like below,

Desired results:

```
ID                 
-----   
1
2                                    
4   
6
```

Is it possible to achieve in SQL Server by splitting, then search in query? I look forward to an experts answer.

Comment: Use a table valued parameter https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: You may try to split the text in the `Company` column and the search pattern using `STRING_SPLIT()` and use the appropriate `WHERE` clause (SQL Server 2016 is needed).

Comment: @dale, Actually I don't know how to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass in a table valued parameter, you can join on that.

So for example

```sql
CREATE TYPE StringList AS TABLE (str varchar(100));
```

```
DECLARE @tmp StringList;
INSERT @tmp (str)
VALUES
('%goog%'),
('%micros%'),
('%amazon%');

SELECT t.ID 
FROM table t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
   FROM @tmp tmp
   WHERE t.Company LIKE tmp.str);
```

The one issue with this is that someone could write `le; Mic` and still get a result.

Strictly speaking, your table design is flawed, because you are storing multiple different items in the same column. You really should have this normalized into rows, so every `Company` is a separate row. Then your code would look like this:

```sql
SELECT t.ID 
FROM table t
JOIN @tmp tmp ON t.Company LIKE tmp.str
GROUP BY t.ID
```

You can simulate it by splitting your string

```sql
SELECT t.ID 
FROM table t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
   FROM STRING_SPLIT(t.Company) s
   JOIN @tmp tmp ON s.value LIKE tmp.str);
```

Comment: Thanks @charlieface. I think, almost I get some Idea. I hope the above query would solve. Let me try.

Comment: the company column is just an example. Actually it's different and also it one input element value from UI for filtering results for admin screen.

Comment: Can't help you further without knowing you exact scenario

Comment: Thank you so much. This would help me to solve rest.